# Error 462: The remote server machine does not exist when working with Word via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I open a Word file programmatically in Excel VBA and add/edit contents using bookmarks.

I find that on alternate runs, I get

> Error 462: The remote server does not exist

I researched and understood this has something to do with 'Unqualified references'.

I don't understand how to correct the code to qualified references.

```
        Set exR = ActiveSheet.Range(TestIdCol & CStr(DataRowNum) & ":" & TestIdCol & CStr(RowEnd))

           ExistingEvidenceDoc = UseFileDialogOpen("Word Documents", "*.doc;*.docx")

           Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

           If ExistingEvidenceDoc <> "" Then
                Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(ExistingEvidenceDoc)
           Else
                Exit Sub
           End If

           objWord.Visible = True
           Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)


           Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

           getExistingEvidences = ExistingTestEvidences(objDoc)
           o = DataRowNum
            For Each cell In exR
                If cell.Value <> "" And Not IsInArray(cell.Value, getExistingEvidences) Then
                    objSelection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
                    objSelection.TypeText text:="Heading " + cell.Value
                    objSelection.TypeParagraph
                    objSelection.MoveLeft
                    objSelection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
                    objSelection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
                    objDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:="BMrk" + CStr(o), Range:=objSelection
                    objSelection.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("Q" + CStr(o)).Select
                           ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Hyperlink", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon _
                                   :=False
                    objSelection.MoveRight

                    'objSelection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Paragraph")
                    objSelection.TypeText text:=Range(DescriptionCol + CStr(cell.Row)).Value
                    objSelection.TypeParagraph


                ElseIf IsInArray(cell.Value, getExistingEvidences) = False Then
                    objSelection.EndKey
                    objSelection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
                    objSelection.TypeText text:="Heading " + cell.Value
                    objSelection.TypeParagraph
                    objSelection.MoveLeft
                    objSelection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
                    objSelection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend
                    objDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:="BMrk" + CStr(o), Range:=objSelection
                    objSelection.Copy
                    ActiveSheet.Range("Q" + CStr(o)).Select
                           ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Hyperlink", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon _
                                   :=False
                    objSelection.MoveRight

                    'objSelection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Paragraph")
                    objSelection.TypeText text:=Range(DescriptionCol + CStr(cell.Row)).Value
                    objSelection.TypeParagraph
                End If

                o = o + 1

            Next cell


        MyErrorHandler:
                MsgBox "SeeHeadingPageNumber" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Err = " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Description: " & Err.Description
```

Additionaly, whatever exR range I define, it completes execution for the entire range but at the end MyErrorHandler is invoked. Is there a reason for it?

Comment: Your error handler is invoked because you are not exiting the sub before you get to it. Add an `exit sub` before `MyErrorHandler:`. Also I don't see an `On Error Goto` anywhere

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  Thanks, that solved one problem...but the main problem remains about the Error 462 encountered. Could you please help me with that too? :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two unqualified references to Word objects:

```
objSelection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
```

which appears twice, needs to be:

```
objSelection.Style = objWord.ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 1")
```

Otherwise you're creating an implicit reference to Word that you can't destroy in your code.

Comment: Thanks mate, this seems to work for now. Let me get back to you incase i run into the issue again. Atleast for a couple of times now, I didnt run into the issue. Thanks a lot again and God bless!

Answer (score 5):

You should first ensure there are no oprhan `winword.exe` in task manager. Kill then or log out/in to get rid of them.

Then you should add something like this code to the end to 'explcitly' close word:

(I'm not sure of the exact syntax, hopefully you can work it out)

```
IF Not(objWord Is Nothing) Then

    objWord.Close(False)
    Set objWord = Nothing

End If
```

You should add something similar to your error handler.

What often happens is during development and debugging, sometimes word doesn't get closed properly and 'orphan' processes hang around even though they are not visible.

You may also wish to use

```
Set objWord = New Word.Application
```

instead of

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

as that gives you autocomplete etc.

But there area advantages to each way.

Answer (score 2):

> ***[SOLVED]*** Err 462 – "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable"

```
ErrResume:
    On Error GoTo ErrPaste
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(ExistingEvidenceDoc)
    On Error GoTo 0

ErrPaste:
  'The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable
    If Err.Number = 462 Then
        Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Resume ErrResume
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to set tabs programmatically. The error message "Error 462: The remote server does not exist" shows up every now and then, but never on the first run after a freshly started Access.

It seems that the global "CentimetersToPoints(5)" was causing the problem.
i replaced

```
oRng.ParagraphFormat.TabStops.Add Position:=CentimetersToPoints(5), Alignment:=wdAlignTabLeft, Leader:=wdTabLeaderSpaces
```

by

```
Call oRng.Paragraphs.TabStops.Add(142, wdAlignTabLeft, wdTabLeaderSpaces)
```

Which performs the same but without errors

Comment: CentimetersToPoints() was also causing this error for me. I changed it to use points rather and haven't got the error again. Weird.