# Weirdness with VBA in Excel and Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have the following code.

```
Sub Run_Queries_In_Access()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim acc As Object
Dim db As Object
Dim r As Long
Dim strDatabasePath As String

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
'Set conn = CreateObject("Access.Application")
strDatabasePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\AI.mdb"
conn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & strDatabasePath & ";" & _
    "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxx"
conn.Open

Set acc = New Access.Application
'acc.Visible = True
Set db = CurrentDb()


Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now) 'Wait for 2 seconds
    acc.DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    acc.DoCmd.OpenQuery "qry_Delete_ALLL"
    Dim qry As Object
    Set qry = db.QueryDefs("qry_HIST")
    qry.Parameters(0) = Range("ASOFDATE")
    qry.Execute

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now) ' Wait for 2 seconds
    Set qry = db.QueryDefs("qry_LIMIT_HIST") ' Run Append Query
    qry.Parameters(0) = Range("ASOFDATE")
    qry.Execute
    acc.DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    ' SELECT ALL DATA
    Set qry = db.QueryDefs("qry_TBL_DATA")
    Worksheets("Impact Analysis").Range("A11:L5000").Clear
    Set daoRcd = qry.OpenRecordset
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Impact Analysis").Range("A11").CopyFromRecordset daoRcd

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing


End Sub
```

I have references set as follows.

[image]

If I step through the code by hitting F8 over and over, everything works fine.  If I fire the code by a button click event, I get the following error message: 'run time error 462: the remote server machine does not exist or is not available'

When I check the code, I see that the db is actually set to nothing!!

[image]

[image]

I'm guessing that it has to do with one of my references, or the way I declared one of my variables, but that's just a guess.  I don't know for sure.  Any ideas would be very welcome!!  Thanks!!

Comment: There should be no reason to have the command `Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)`.

Comment: When debugging, setting `Application.Visible = True` can help, then you can see if the code opens the database, and some extra messages/popups (`OpenCurrentDatabase` doesn't generate errors on an incorrect passwords, I use `Acc.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(Path, False, False, ";PWD=" & password)` to check if I can create a valid connection to the database, especially when users enter the password, this throws a runtime error on an incorrect pass)

Comment: *I see that the db is actually set to nothing!!* - at this point the line wasn't executed yet, so it's natural that the variable isn't set yet.

Comment: Do you maybe have the line 
On Error Resume Next
somewhere in the code executed?

Comment: @Gustav, I added Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now) to slow it down a little; I though it was going too fast and tripping over itself, or something like that.  @ Andre, Good catch.  Still, when I hit F8 and that line of code is evaluated, it still says db = Nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by _"When I check the code..."_? What is it that you do to check it?

Comment: `Dim daoRcd As Recordset` sounds like you want to use the normal DAO methods. So I would set a reference to the `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library` instead of `ActiveX Data Objects`. And then `Dim db As DAO.Database`. -- I tested your code on my system, it ran successfully every time (with and without `Application.Wait`), with ADO reference and also with DAO reference. -- Another thing to try: remove the database password.

Comment: It must be something on my network or I am missing some kind of critical update.  I have done this many times in the past, and I've never encountered any issues whatsoever.  Things are completely different at my current place of employment.  The security is so tie here that I can't even play an MP3 on my machine, never mind do anything useful.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your code.  At the point where you have a break (i.e., the line you have highlighted), the variable "db" is not set to anything.  Step to the next line and *then* check the value of db and it should be set to whatever the database is named.

As for the actual issue at hand, you may want to check this post:

[Running into Error 462: The remote server machine does not exist when working with WORD via Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030584/running-into-error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-when-working-wi)

Even though it deals with Word, it may give you a clue as to why it's happening for you.

There's also this post which may help as well:

["Run-time error 462 : The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable" when running VBA code a second time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631641/run-time-error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-or-is-unavailable)

Since you didn't post your entire code, it's hard to tell what the issue might be.  If either of these helps, please come back and post a comment under here that explains what you did and how you fixed it, just in case it happens to anyone else.

Comment: I just posted the code.  I made a couple tiny changes, but nothing major.  Now, I am getting 'the command or action SetWarnings isn't available now' on this line: 'acc.DoCmd.SetWarnings False'

Comment: @All, I ended up writing some standard VBA code to do the Access stuff purely in Access and the Excel stuff purely in Excel.  The Excel/Access integration concept just didn't work for me, and I couldn't waste any more time with it.  I think my firm's systems are just too old.  A lot of technologies that we use are 20+ years old.  Thing that should work seamlessly, just do not work no matter what you do.  Thanks for the help everyone.