# Run-Time Error '462'

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to run a macro from excel that will open up an existing word document, populate the fields from excel to word via content controls, and paste/format a table into the word document at a certain location. About 20% of the time, I'll get this Run Time Error 462 stating "The remote Server Machine Does Not Exist or is Unavailable". I will provide the code and the section where is usually gets stuck at as everything after works 100% of the time. Please help on this.

```
Public Sub Agreement()
    With Sheets("Price List Table")
        .ListObjects(1).Name = "Table1"
    End With

    Dim tbl As Excel.Range    
    Dim wrdApp    
    Dim wrdDoc       
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table       
    Dim c As Integer

    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet2.Name).ListObjects("Table1").Range    
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    wrdApp.Visible = False

    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\Documents\Example")       
    With wrdDoc       
        tbl.Copy    
        wrdApp.Selection.Find.Text = "This is the section for the table to be pasted below it."    
        wrdApp.Selection.Find.Execute   
        wrdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=5, Extend:=wdMove    
        wrdApp.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False

        Dim objTable As Object    
        For Each objTable In ActiveDocument.Tables ' (This is where the error occurs)
            objTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
            objTable.AllowAutoFit = True
        Next

        wrdApp.Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, 1
        wrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=GoToNext
        wrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=GoToNext
        wrdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToTable, Which:=GoToNext
        wrdApp.Selection.Tables(1).Select

        With wrdApp.Selection.Borders(wdBorderTop)
            .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
            .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
            .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
        End With
        With wrdApp.Selection.Borders(wdBorderLeft)
            .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
            .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
            .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
        End With
        With wrdApp.Selection.Borders(wdBorderBottom)
            .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
            .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
            .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
        End With
        With wrdApp.Selection.Borders(wdBorderRight)
            .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
            .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
            .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
        End With
        With wrdApp.Selection.Borders(wdBorderHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
            .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
            .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
        End With
        With wrdApp.Selection.Borders(wdBorderVertical)
            .LineStyle = Options.DefaultBorderLineStyle
            .LineWidth = Options.DefaultBorderLineWidth
            .Color = Options.DefaultBorderColor
        End With

        wrdApp.Selection.Tables(1).Columns(3).Select
        wrdApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
        wrdApp.Selection.Tables(1).Columns(4).Select
        wrdApp.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
```

Comment: It looks like a similar question has been posted before, Run Time Error 462 has to do with unqualified references to Word objects when you're working in Excel VBA. Have a read through the answers, if you fix your references, the error should go away. Check out the similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030584/running-into-error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-when-working-wi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running into Error 462: The remote server machine does not exist when working with WORD via Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030584/running-into-error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-when-working-wi)

Comment: Try `For Each objTable In wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables`

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. It worked. Such a simple fix but I’m still new to VBA. Appreciate it!