# Inserting multiple tables from Excel to Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am having an issue with my code, I am trying to copy 3 different table/cell locations within Excel and then Paste those values/tables within Word. I want to paste them directly below one another.

I keep getting a

> Run Time Error of 5941. 
>   "Application Defined or Object Defined Error"

I tried looking up what this could mean but I am having no luck. I found this reference from this site: [Run Time Error StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030584/running-into-error-462-the-remote-server-machine-does-not-exist-when-working-wi) but no luck figuring out my problem.

My Code:

```
Sub TalkToWord()
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, wdRng As Word.Range
Dim myCat As Integer: myCat = InputBox("Enter your Category: ")
Dim myConfig As Long: myConfig = InputBox("Enter your Config #: ")
Dim myGradeName As String: myGradeName = InputBox("Enter your Grade Name: ")
Dim myDept As Integer: myDept = InputBox("Enter your Dept: ")
Dim myClass As Integer: myClass = InputBox("Enter your Class/Subclass: ")
Dim mySeason As String: mySeason = InputBox("Enter your Season Code: ")
myTimeFrame = Application.InputBox("Enter your Time Frame: ", FormatDateTime(Date, vbShortDate))

With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc.Range
    .PageSetup.TopMargin = InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Font.Underline = True
    .InsertAfter "FY 19 CAT " & myCat
    .InsertParagraphAfter
    Set wdRng = .Characters.Last
    With wdRng
      .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
      .ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = InchesToPoints(-0.7)
      .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 5
      .Font.Underline = False
      .Font.Size = 12
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .InsertAfter ("Grade Number:")
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .InsertAfter ("Config #:")
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .InsertAfter ("Grade Name:" & myGradeName)
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .InsertAfter (Chr(9) & "-" & "Dept:" & myDept)
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .InsertAfter (Chr(9) & "-" & "Class/Subclass:" & myClass)
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .InsertAfter (Chr(9) & "-" & "Season Code:" & mySeason)
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .InsertAfter (Chr(9) & "-" & "TimeFrame:" & myTimeFrame)
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .InsertAfter (Chr(9) & "-" & "Grade Type:" & myGradeType)
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .InsertAfter (Chr(9) & "-" & "Index Breakpoint Bands by Volume Grade:")
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .InsertParagraphAfter
      .InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .PageSetup.TopMargin = InchesToPoints(0.1)
     --- Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", "B2").Copy
      .Paste
      .Tables(1).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
      .InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .PageSetup.TopMargin = InchesToPoints(0.1)
      Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K1", "Q2").Copy
      .Paste
      .Tables(2).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
      .InsertBreak Type:=wdLineBreak
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .PageSetup.TopMargin = InchesToPoints(0.1)
      Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("K4", "Q6").Copy
      .Paste
      .Tables(3).Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter
    End With
  End With
End With
End Sub
```

The error Occurs on the Line with the 3 dashes.

I am new to VBA so please go easy on me!

EDIT: It will Create the Word Document

Comment: Where does this code run at? Word or Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code is being run from the workbook you're copying things from, try changing the problem line from

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", "B2").Copy
```

to

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1", "B2").Copy
```

Comment: This I believe worked but now I am getting an error stating that the With Block Object is not defined and running through the code with "F8" It seemed to be the second with Block:                         Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc.Range

Comment: Is there a better way to produce the above code without so many With Blocks?

Comment: @AlexFields That's a different question - you should ask a new one. And mark this one as answered (click the check mark to the left o the answer, assuming it helped solve *the question you originally asked*.) Although asking for a "better" way to do something tends to get a question closed as "primarily opinion based". I can tell you that I would not NEST these With blocks. Each can and should be on its own. The code could be further optimized by concatenating the strings being inserted. It's possible to use `& vbCr` instead of `.InsertParagraphAfter`