# VBA Object not created?

Tags: vba, object, powerpoint

in the following Code I **sometimes, not always!** get an error at "Set PP = pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptVorlage)". When I check the value of "pptApp" in the immediate window using "?pptApp", VBA can't return a value.

What does this mean? Was the Object not created? Or set to null during the code?

Thanks in advance!

```
Public myfilename As String

Sub Saveas_PDF()
    Dim PP As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim company As String
    Set DropDown.ws_company = Tabelle2
    company = DropDown.ws_company.Range("C2").Value

    Dim strPOTX As String
    Dim strPfad As String
    Dim pptApp As Object

    Call filepicker

    Dim Cell As Range

    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

    For Each Cell In DropDown.ws_company.Range(DropDown.ws_company.Cells(5, 3), DropDown.ws_company.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Dim pptVorlage As String
        pptVorlage = myfilename

        Set PP = pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptVorlage) 'sometimes error (remote server machine not found.) + pptApp seems to be empty?
        PP.UpdateLinks
        pptApp.Visible = True
        Debug.Print (PP.Name)
        AppActivate (PP.Name)
        PP.Close
        Set PP = Nothing
    Next

    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    If IsAppRunning("PowerPoint.Application") Then
        If pptApp.Windows.Count = 0 Then

            pptApp.Quit
        End If
    End If

    Set pptApp = Nothing
End Sub

Sub filepicker()

 Dim i As Variant
 MsgBox ("In the following dialog please choose the current file")
 Dim myfilenamepicker As FileDialog
 Set myfilenamepicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
 myfilenamepicker.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\XY"
 myfilenamepicker.Show
 If myfilenamepicker.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
 myfilename = myfilenamepicker.SelectedItems(1)
 End If


End Sub

Function IsAppRunning(ByVal sAppName) As Boolean
    Dim oApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oApp = GetObject(, sAppName)
    If Not oApp Is Nothing Then
    Set oApp = Nothing
    IsAppRunning = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: How is `myfilename` being populated? The error could be because the file doesn't exist?

Comment: No, you would not get "remote server machine not found." if `pptApp` was `Nothing`. You would get error 91.

Comment: @Ryan thank you for the reply. I added the code of the file picker s8ub filepicker), which returns the variable "myfilename". Also using "?myfilename" VBA returns a value when the error occurs.

Comment: @GSerg: Thanks for the reply! Do you know what can be the problem then? Also why does the variable not return a value, when thsi error occurs?

Comment: Please provide complete actual error messages and codes.

Comment: @Underhook32 thanks. Is `myfilename` declared as public? I don't see it declared anywhere. You may not have scope inside `Saveas_PDF`.

Comment: Jap, sry forgot that Public myfilename As String

Comment: Code is complete now!

Comment: Any other ideas / suggestions? :)

Comment: @GSerg: Error is "462: "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable".

Can you help me? Also the PPT crashes, which might be important to know

Comment: @Underhook32 Do you have [stray powerpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26030584/11683) running?

Comment: @GSerg: Thanks for the quick reply. To what are you referring when you talk about "stray powerpoints"? I have one other PPT file open before starting the macro if that is what you meant

Comment: https://tagasanjose.blogspot.com/2014/09/powerpoint-crashes-on-close-vba.html

I tried this workaround. So far my code works. But why does PPT crash??? very weird, really would like to understand

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is due to the code in the question having two identical lines:

```
Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
```

Each line will cause VBA to start up a new instance of PowerPoint, and it tries to assign them to the same object variable (`pptApp`). This is the cause of the remote server error.

Comment out the second line that starts a new instance of PowerPoint and see if things don't work better - or at least differently.

Comment: Hi Cindy, thanks for the reply. I just commented out the line and tested the code again. Unfortunately after a couple of runs I get the error again :/

Comment: @Underhook32 The error is certainly because *something(s)* is/are being held open. If you comment out the If block `If IsAppRunning` does that change anything? How about if the `For Each` is reduced to only one or two executions? (`PP` might not be cleaned up adequately before the next loop...?)

Comment: 1. First of all sry, did not know that, will follow that rule in the future!
               2. I will test it. On question upfront. How can I make sure that "PP" gets cleared? is Set PP = Nothing not enough?

Comment: I would expect it should be enough, but it may be a "timing" issue. If fewer loops don't cause a problem - no matter how often the entire macro is run, then sticking a `Do Events` in there might help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Cindy / besten Dank ;) Can you elaborate what you mean by "timing" issue?

I tested the code with only one loop, but I still get the error message. I also tried Do Events, but was not sure where to put it. Directly in front of the line that does not work?